# java maven project structure refactor

Tags: java, maven, jar, compilation

I have a maven project structure like this. It's a java web application. I use Idea as my IDE. `controller` relies on `Core.java`, `Core.java` relies on `util/.`.

```
|-com
  |-domain
    |-app
      |-controller
        |- xxx.java
      |-service
        |- xxx.java
      |-dao
        |- xxx.java
      |-util
        |- xxx.java
      |-core
        |-Core.java
```

'Core.java' is an engine class, I want it could be replaced easily so I can change the engine for my different clients in a simple way (I do not need to change any code outside the engine). I have an idea is move it to a standalone jar like this

```
'engine.jar'
|-com
  |-domain
    |-app
      |-core
        |-Core.java
```

And remove origin file in my project. I just need to import `engine.jar` to my project when I need this engine (or another engine). After this the project structure in my IDE looks like

```
src
|-java
  |-main
    |-com
      |-domain
        |-app
          |-controller
            |- xxx.java
          |-service
            |- xxx.java
          |-dao
            |- xxx.java
          |-util
            |- xxx.java
External Libraries
|-xxx
|-xxx
|-engine.jar
   |-com
     |-domain
       |-app
         |-core
           |-Core.java
```

It did not work. The class in `controller` can not find `Core.java`, it shows a red wavy line in `import com.domain.app.core.Core`. But `Core.java` can find it's relies in `util/.`. So the project can not pass compile.

My question is: How could I make this work? Or my solution is wrong and this would never work?

Comment: Can you post at last your pom.xml code, to see where the error is?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not the way it is done.

You don't copy jars into Maven projects. You declare them as `<dependency>` in the POM.